# (Scheme) Using the map function, how do you find the sum of the sublists of a list?

Tags: dictionary, scheme, addition, sublist

So, I'm trying to add up the sublists of a list. Like, if I have something like this:

```
(add-pair '((1 4) (2 1)))
```

I want it to return this:

```
(5 3)
```

This is what I have so far:

```
(define pair-additions
  (lambda (ls)
    (map
      (lambda (n)
        (+ (car n) (cdr n)))ls)))
```

Right now, it's giving me an error saying that the input isn't a number. Can anybody help me out?

Comment: Note you could also use `apply` here: `(map (lambda (x) (apply + x)) '((1 4) (2 1))) ;=> (5 3)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You almost got it! here is the problem:

```
(+ (car n) (cdr n))
```

For retrieving the second element of a list, you have to take the `car` of the `cdr`, not just the `cdr`. Change the above line for this:

```
(+ (car n) (car (cdr n)))
```

Or for this, which is a short form of the previous line:

```
(+ (car n) (cadr n))
```

Or for this, which is easier to read (if supported by your Scheme interpreter):

```
(+ (first n) (second n))
```

All the above are equivalent.

Comment: Cool. I was close. Thanks for your help!